# How to override auto generated URL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to override the Rails auto generated URL? For example, say you have a a comment object that is polymorphic to Photo and Post. Let's say we want to handle the comment object differently for each parent, so we have two controllers:

```
resources :photo, shallow: true do
  resources :comments, controller: :photo_comments
#...
resources :post, shallow: true do
  resources :comments, controller: :post_comments
end
```

Now I want to do this:

```
# A Photo comment
= link_to "Open", comment # => /photo_comment/1

# A Post comment
= link_to "Open", comment # => /post_comment/2
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to qualify the entire path, i.e. `link_to "Show", photo_comment_path(comment)`?

I prefer not to use nested routes.

Comment: If you're iterating over a group of comments, that should work as you have it.

Comment: @Clark I'm afraid not. That would produce `/comments/1` and `/comments/2`, which means the URLs would clash. The router will not know if I want to hit the `/photo_comments` or `post_comments` controller.

Comment: I see, what about with something like this `resources :comments, controller: :photo_comments, path: '/photo_comments'`?

Answer (score 1):

The URL in question is generated by polymorphic_url. The way I see it, you don't really need to override it, just pass in the parent along with the comment, like this:

```
link_to "Open", [:whatever_namespace_there_is, comment.parent, comment]
```

This is more flexible than specifying the path via helper method, and it saves you the trouble of checking the parent's type manually.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, to answer your question, you would override/copy methods from `gems/actionview-<ver>/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper` and `../helpers/tag_helper` depending on how you wanted to do it. Then you would create a .rb file in `config/initializers` Here is an example of how it would work

```
ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.module_eval do
  def link_to_comment(comment_controller, name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block) 
    #create new method based on original, add new controller argument
    html_options, options, name = options, name, block if block_given?
    options ||= {}

    html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)

    url = url_for(options)
    urla = url.split("/")#let it generate the url
    url = ""
    urla.each do |part|
      unless part == "comments"#go through each part and find the comments section
        url<<part
        url<<"/"
      else
        url<<comment_controller#put the controller where it needs to be
        url<<"_"
        url<<part
        url<<"/"
      end
    end
     html_options['href'] ||= url

    content_tag(:a, name || url, html_options, &block)
  end
end
```

You would call this method when you needed, `<%= link_to_comment("post", "View", comment) %>`

Restart your server and it should be implemented. This will work if you have routes for `/post_comment/` and not `/comment/` if both of your comments resources use the same path you'd need to define it like this `resources :comments, controller: :photo_comments, path: '/photo_comments'` and you shouldn't need to do any method overriding.